# Why using Mingw64 when you enter a value, it is displayed again in Clion?

Tags: c++, compilation, cygwin, mingw, clion

Why is it that while using mingw64 when you enter a value, it is displayed again?

When using Cygwin it does not.

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBdwp.jpg

Comment: Does the same result occurs when running the program in release and separately from IDE?

Comment: @Satus This occurs only in the IDE.

Comment: Then you should ask Clion guys or report a bug on their bugtracker. ) Also  I used to have similar issues with Clion debugger. It is really slow and buggy, they are doing their best to fix it, and it is much better then it was on alpha, but it is still not really good.

Comment: I asked, but no one has yet answered. devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/473303 Maybe someone experienced this here. I really like the IDEs from JetBrains, I hope they will improve Clion :) I created a ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4663

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put code in there **as text** (indented 4 spaces), so that it is searchable.